# npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'

Tags: docker, npm, alpine-linux

I am running docker file to create the container and getting below error:

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
npm WARN app No description
npm WARN app No repository field.
npm WARN app No README data
npm WARN app No license field.
```

Docker File:

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY package.jason .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Package.jason is available in the project folder. So my project folder would look like

```
../
Dockerfile
package.jason
index.js
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might find it easier to build a complete working application without using Docker, and package it as a final deployment step.  Outside of Docker, can you `npm install`, `npm test`, and `npm start` your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that the file is named package.jason :). Can you rename it to the correct value, "package.json"?

Comment: Update the answer to remove the assumption that everyone can see it is a small typo in the file extension. I thought it was clear from the context that the extension should be json.